# USB key board & USB mouse idle time in linux

Tags: linux

How to get the Idle time in Linux(ex: ubuntu) when using USB keyboard and USB mouse, i don't want to use 'XOpenDisplay' because it uses 'X11/Xlib.h' file which is not there as a default when we install the OS,
and we have to install 'libx11-dev & libxss-dev' packages for this, and xprintidle also uses the same library(Xlib.h).

We can get idle time of PS-2 keyboard & mouse from '/proc/interrupts'.

How system detects idleness with out any external libraries?
because as a fresh OS when we set a monitor off time and lock screen time in power management it easily detects idleness of the user logged in and controls the activity.